# Pyramid wih chars in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that draws a pyramid in java and i have to type the height the char i want to use, how many spaces from the begin and with how many chars should start

I made the pyramid but how to tell the program with how many chars should start(ex Height = 10 and start with 3 chars)

My code

```
    public void Tr (int height, int begin, int spaces) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height - 1 - i; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < i * 2 + 1; k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Scanner class for fetching inputs from the user.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the height of the pyramid :- ");
int height = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the  number of characters of the pyramid to start with :- ");
int start = s.nextInt();
```

Other option could be use to use `String[] array` of main method...

```
java Pyramid 5 4    
// passed arguments as default inputs to program(calling Pyramid class)
```

Comment: I get the input from the user but the pyramid always starts with 1 character

Comment: @Alex- That is because of the second inner loop! Change this piece of code--->`for (int k = 0; k < i * 2 + 1; k++){
            System.out.print("*");` and include another inside loop inside this to represent inner n number of stars...

Comment: I was trying that but it always starts with some number and height - begin

Comment: You need to be more specific! One can't do everything without clear idea and your output!

Comment: NO,because the question needs to be more specific---what you want??? At least the output or anything to what to print?

Comment: I want that the user inputs that the triangle should start with 3 chars (height 10 and start with 3 chars at the top)

Comment: Please add a new question for that issue!

Answer (score 0):

The code written below is a very simple form of a simple answer to your problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Half_Pyramid
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output you will get will be:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

and to make a full pyramid you could add an inverted half pyramid program to the same then you will get:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```